# Programmatically click a button in Excel through Macro (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, button

I have a custom-button, linked to a macro which does a few things. After they are done, I want the code to programmatically click the below highlighted button (more clearly, open the import XML dialog), so my user could see the file selection window and it would proceed for it's further tasks.

Representative image

[image]

Here's my current macro code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()
    ' ... All my existing macro code
    
    ' ---------- programmatically click the Import button (from Developer) here ------------
End Sub
```

What should I add in my macro to achieve this?

Comment: What are the assumptions ?  i.e. will that file always be open in user's workstation and instead of waiting user to click on that, do you want excel to open that dialog and force the user to select a data source ?

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Your post as it stands, suggests you're treating SO like a free coding service. Whereas its real purpose is for coders to help other coders solve specific issues. Please read [help] on asking questions. In general, you need to 1) Make an effort to solve the problem yourself 2) Post what you've tried so far. 3) Explain why that isn't working and/or not doing what you're aiming to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my question -

```
% - Alt
l - Developer
t - Import
```

are the shortcut keys to import an XML into the sheet, and this command runs the shortcut keys programmatically, opening my desired file selection box. -

```
Application.SendKeys ("%lt")
```

Comment: `SendKeys` is rarely a good solution. You will eventually run into a problem using it.

Answer (score 0):

CommandBars.ExecuteMso method:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Office.CommandBars.ExecuteMso

"Executes the control identified by the **idMso** parameter."
Hover over the button where you would add it to the ribbon, you will see the text includes "XmlImport"

"This method is useful in cases where there is no object model for a particular command. Works on controls that are built-in buttons, toggleButtons, and splitButtons."

```vb
Private Sub ExecuteMso_MoveToFolder()
    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Office.CommandBars.ExecuteMso
    ' Hover over the button where you would add it to the ribbon,
    '  you will see the text includes "XmlImport"

    CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("XmlImport")
End Sub
```